# Can't figure out how to complete the chomp game, arrays don't work?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement

So we got this a school assignment. it is a chomp game and the requirements are these:

The program should have the functions below and pointers and structs are not allowed. Also it should have the global variables that I have declared (except for m and n. More global variables and functions is allowed to have if one wishes to.

a) initialize() Initialize every position in the matrix to 'O'. No parameters or return value.

b) print_board() Prints the matrix. No parameters or return value.

c) get_move() Scan a move from the player (row and col) and "return" it with an array. Parameters: Information about whos turn it is (Player 1 or Player 2), and an array with two elements where the move coordinates will be stored. No return value.

d) check_move() Controls if a move is legal (not outside the matrix and not a position that has already been eaten). Parameters: The move that is going to be checked (row and col). Return value: Result of the control.

e) update_board() Updates the matrix. Parameters: The new move (row and col). No return value.

... I feel like I am almost done, but when I enter the values, the board "paints" with a different result. And I don't know where I've done wrong.

Also, even though I don't need it for the assignment, any suggestions on how to improve the code are welcome!

Oh! And also, when I enter a coordinate into the terminal, it actually needs to be inversed (vertically at least) and it is 4 in the morning and I can't figure out how?
Thank you all in advance!

here is some output examples:

```
Welcome to Chomp!

+----------+
|OOOOOOOOOO|
|OOOOOOOOOO|
|OOOOOOOOOO|
|XOOOOOOOOO|
+----------+


Player 1: Your move, please! (row,col): 3,7
+----------+
|OOOOOO    |
|OOOOOO    |
|OOOOOO    |
|XOOOOOOOOO|
+----------+

Player 2: Your move, please! (row,col): 3,1     <= Bad move!
+----------+
|          |
|          |
|          |
|XOOOOOOOOO|
+----------+

Player 1: Your move, please! (row,col): 4,2     <= Good move!
+----------+
|          |
|          |
|          |
|X         |
+----------+

Player 2: Your move, please! (row,col): 4,2
Already taken!

Player 2: Your move, please! (row,col): 4,11
Illegal position!

Player 2: Your move, please! (row,col): 4,1
Game over, player 2 has been poisoned!
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


// Global variables
int height = 4;
int width = 10;
int player = 2;
int move[2] = {0};
char board[4][10];
int m;
int n;


void Initialize();
void PrintBoard();
void GetMove(int player, int move[2]);
int CheckMove(int move[2]);
void UpdateBoard(int move[2]);


int main(void)
{
Initialize();

 while(1)
    {
        PrintBoard();
        player = (player == 2) ? 1 : 2;

        while(1)
        {
            GetMove(player, move);
            int c = CheckMove(move);
            if (c == 0) 
            { 
                UpdateBoard(move); 
                break;
            }
            else if (c == 1)
            {
                printf("\nAlready taken. Please try again! (row col): ");
                continue;
            }
            else if (c == 2)
            {
                printf("\nYou lost!\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else if (c == 3)
            {
                printf("\nIllegal move. Try again! (row col): ");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

}

void Initialize()
{
        memset(board, 'O' , sizeof(char) * height * width);
        board[3][0] = 'X';
}
void PrintBoard()
{
    printf("\n+----------+\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 11; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == 11)
            {
                printf("|");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", board[i][j-1]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("+----------+\n");
}
void GetMove(int player, int move[2])
{
    printf("\nPlayer %d: your move! (row col): ", player);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) scanf(" %d", &move[i]);
}
int CheckMove(int move[2])
{
    int check = 99;
    if ((move[0] >= 1  && move[0] < 5) && (move[1] >= 1  && move[1] <= 10))
    {
        printf("move = %d %d\n", move[0], move[1]);
        int m = move[0] - 1;
        int n = move[1] - 1;
        printf("move = %d %d\n", m, n);
        // move[0] -= 1;
        // move[1] -= 1;
        // more checks
        if (board[m][n] == 'Z')
        {
            check = 1;
        }
        else if(board[m][n] == 'X')
        {
            check = 2;
        }
        else 
        {
            check = 0;
        }
    }
else { check = 3; }
return check;    
}
void UpdateBoard(int move[2])
{
    // int y = move[0];
    // int x = move[1];

    for (int i = m; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = n; j < width; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = 'Z';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should update your post with the requirement and some example input with the output and the expected output.

but anyways, I have read your code and apparently you have only 2 problems:

1. in the line

   ```
   int m = move[0] - 1;
   int n = move[1] - 1;
   ```

actually, you are shallowing the global variables, even my compiler gave me this warning:

> Declaration shadows a variable in the global scope

so instead, you should do:

```
    m = move[0] - 1;
    n = move[1] - 1;
```

this will make you global variables could be modified

---

2. in the lines:

   ```
   for (int i = m; i >= 0; i--)
   {
        for (int j = n; j < width; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = 'Z';
        }
    }
   ```

if the user chooses a specific row and column, this code will mark an entire row from position (m, n) with the value `Z` not only one cell

so you should do simply:

```
board[m][n] = 'Z';
```

with these being fixed, this is some example output:

```
+----------+
|OOOOOOOOOO|
|OOOOOOOOOO|
|OOOOOOOOOO|
|XOOOOOOOOO|
+----------+

Player 1: your move! (row col):1 2
 move = 1 2
move = 0 1

+----------+
|OZOOOOOOOO|
|OOOOOOOOOO|
|OOOOOOOOOO|
|XOOOOOOOOO|
+----------+

Player 2: your move! (row col):2 1
 move = 2 1
move = 1 0

+----------+
|OZOOOOOOOO|
|ZOOOOOOOOO|
|OOOOOOOOOO|
|XOOOOOOOOO|
+----------+

Player 1: your move! (row col):1 2
 move = 1 2
move = 0 1

Already taken. Please try again! (row col):
Player 1: your move! (row col):3 1
 move = 3 1
move = 2 0

+----------+
|OZOOOOOOOO|
|ZOOOOOOOOO|
|ZOOOOOOOOO|
|XOOOOOOOOO|
+----------+

Player 2: your move! (row col):4 1
 move = 4 1
move = 3 0

You lost!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, it works much better just because of that little thing... actually the program should remove whole rows and columns to the top and right of the coordinates that the user enters, and the last person to press x, loses.. I have now edited my post so it is clearer!

Comment: @DimitriMikhalev, what do you mean by saying  `I enter a coordinate into the terminal, it actually needs to be inversed (vertically at least)` and also why in your edited post, the input **3,1** is considered a bad move ?

Comment: sorry for slow answer. needed to sleep, etc. By inversed I mean that for instance coordinate **1,1** is where the **X** is and it goes up and to the right from there. But right now, **X** is **(3,0)**... **3,1** is a bad move because the space is already empty from *O:s*... (I have decided to use Z instead of just empty spaces, to see better.. the players take turns in choosing a position labeled "O" and "eat" all the positions the the top and right of that position. The player left with eating the X, loses